# what is the relationship between safe & pure & referential transparency in functional programming?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, purely-functional

1. pure / impure: appears when we talk about the different between Haskell and lisp-family.
2. safe / unsafe: appears when we name functions like unsafePerformIO, unsafeCoerce.
3. referential transparency / referential opacity: appears when we emphasize the benefit of purely functional programming.

The difference between these words are very subtle, I find there is some post talking about them individually, but I'm still hoping there is a clear comparison between them, and I can't find such a post here yet.

Comment: [Pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional_programming) means that functions are modelled as mathematical functions and have no side-effects. Safe in the context of Haskell can mean [many things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804032/what-is-an-unsafe-function-in-haskell), e.g. type safety. [Referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) is a consequence of the use of pure functions.

Comment: @SimonShine Thanks for your comment, why not post an answer?  And why people here doesn't accept this question?  can I get any suggestion from you?

Comment: I've always been fond of Amr's 1998 paper that explored a similar question with the rigor it deserved: https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~sabry/papers/purelyFunctional.ps

Comment: You know you are comparing noe language with a whole family of languages that have different capabilities on this matter? It's like saying Algol-family doesn't do tail recursion, but it does since JavaScript got it last year, Scala has it so then you cannot talk about Algol as it only had one set of features.

Comment: @luochen1990: I just googled and summarized the first results. The reason given for closing the question is mainly that it's too broad, but I would say that it shows very little effort, happens to be slightly opinionated (which you probably didn't know) and essentially comes down to finding encyclopedic definitions (asking for references to resources).

Answer (score 4):

I've always been fond of Amr Sabry's 1998 paper that explored a similar question with the rigor it deserved: https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~sabry/papers/purelyFunctional.ps

A sample quote:

> A language is purely functional if (i) it includes every simply typed
>   lambda-calculus term, and (ii) its call-by-name, call-by-need, and
>   call-by-value implementations are equivalent modulo divergence and
>   errors.

While this question can generate a lot of "opinion" based answers (which I am carefully avoiding!), reading through Amr's paper can put you in the right mindset about how to think about this question; regardless whether you end up agreeing with him or not.