# How to implement EnumSystemLocalesEx binding with Haskell FFI?

Tags: haskell, winapi, ffi

I am trying to implement a Haskell binding to the Win32 API's [`EnumSystemLocalesEx` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-enumsystemlocalesex), with only partial success. I would like to know why and how to fix things.

My binding looks like this (with the necessary imports from the modules of the `Win32` package):

```
type LOCALE_ENUMPROCEX = LPWSTR -> DWORD -> LPARAM -> IO BOOL
foreign import WINDOWS_CCONV "wrapper"
  mkLOCALE_ENUMPROCEX :: LOCALE_ENUMPROCEX -> IO (FunPtr LOCALE_ENUMPROCEX)

enumSystemLocalesEx :: LOCALE_ENUMPROCEX -> DWORD -> LPARAM -> IO ()
enumSystemLocalesEx callback dwFlags lParam = do
  c_callback <- mkLOCALE_ENUMPROCEX callback
  failIfFalse_ "EnumSystemLocalesEx" $
    c_EnumSystemLocalesEx c_callback dwFlags lParam nullPtr
  freeHaskellFunPtr c_callback
foreign import WINDOWS_CCONV unsafe "windows.h EnumSystemLocalesEx"
  c_EnumSystemLocalesEx :: (FunPtr LOCALE_ENUMPROCEX)
                        -> DWORD
                        -> LPARAM
                        -> LPVOID
                        -> IO Bool
```

My simple test of that looks like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  enumSystemLocalesEx callback 1 0

callback :: LOCALE_ENUMPROCEX
callback c_locale _ _ = do
  locale <- peekTString c_locale
  putStrLn $ "locale is: " <> show locale
  pure True
```

The partial success is as follows. Compiling and running that test executable generates about 120-odd lines of output in alphabetical order, then the executable 'hangs' and produces no more output and does not return - extract below (with `en-ER` being the last of the output; clearly there are more system locales than that):

```
locale is: ""
locale is: "aa"
locale is: "aa-DJ"
locale is: "aa-ER"
locale is: "aa-ET"
...
locale is: "en-CY"
locale is: "en-DE"
locale is: "en-DK"
locale is: "en-DM"
locale is: "en-ER"
```

It is as if some sort of 'capacity' has been used up somewhere.

EDIT: If I change the output to `putStrLn $ "The locale to be displayed is: " <> show locale` (more characters), it 'hangs' earlier (at `"ebu"`). If I change it to `print locale` (fewer characters), it 'hangs' later (at `"en-MH"`). If I change it to no output (`callback _ _ _ = pure True`) it still 'hangs', so it is not the output itself that is problematic. Also, the behaviour is the same in Command Prompt as it is in Windows Terminal. I am using Windows 10 version 2004 and building with `stack`, resolver `lts-16.12` (GHC 8.8.4).

Comment: I can get the full output without hanging using C/C++ on windows 10 2004.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have test the sample in the same environment as yours, and I've get the error "schedule: re-entered unsafely.":

[image]

And if I remove the keyword `unsafe`, then the sample works for me:
[image]

Here is the sample I am using:

```
import System.Win32.Types
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.C
type LOCALE_ENUMPROCEX = LPWSTR -> DWORD -> LPARAM -> IO BOOL
foreign import ccall "wrapper"
  mkLOCALE_ENUMPROCEX :: LOCALE_ENUMPROCEX -> IO (FunPtr LOCALE_ENUMPROCEX)

enumSystemLocalesEx :: LOCALE_ENUMPROCEX -> DWORD -> LPARAM -> IO ()
enumSystemLocalesEx callback dwFlags lParam = do
  c_callback <- mkLOCALE_ENUMPROCEX callback
  failIfFalse_ "EnumSystemLocalesEx" $
    c_EnumSystemLocalesEx c_callback dwFlags lParam nullPtr
  freeHaskellFunPtr c_callback
foreign import ccall "windows.h EnumSystemLocalesEx"
  c_EnumSystemLocalesEx :: (FunPtr LOCALE_ENUMPROCEX)
                        -> DWORD
                        -> LPARAM
                        -> LPVOID
                        -> IO Bool


main :: IO ()
main = do
  enumSystemLocalesEx callback 1 0
  putStrLn "Succeed"

callback :: LOCALE_ENUMPROCEX
callback c_locale _ _ = do
  locale <- peekTString c_locale
  putStrLn $ "locale is: " <> show locale
  pure True
```

It seems that *If you annotate a foreign import declaration with the unsafe keyword, this indicates to the compiler that the call will not invoke another Haskell function, directly or indirectly.* Check the answers in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804032/what-is-an-unsafe-function-in-haskell) for details.

Comment: Thanks. In the light of it, I reference also the last paragraph of section 8.4.3 of the [Haskell 2020 Language Report](https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf).